# How can I verify that copyItematPath is completed in swift?

Tags: swift, copy

I have issue related to copy to specific path in swift.I want to upload image from path to which i have copied Image. but at that time Image not found until file copied  at specific path. So how  can i verify that Copy Operation is completed ?

Comment: `copyItemAtPath:` is sync, no? Or is the issue about the async of the upload?

Comment: do {
                    try FileManager().copyItem(at: sourceURL, to: destinationURL)            
      } catch let error as NSError {
                     // Catch fires here, with an NSError being thrown
                     print("error occurred, here are the details:\n \(error)")
         }   I am using inbuilt Copy Function .

Comment: Is there is no error, the copy should have been completed.

Comment: it doesn't display any error.But I want completion that File is Copied 100 %.

Comment: I don't understand. If you type what you wrote, the next line of code after that is called when it's completed. It's not said in the doc that's it's an async task.